# How to get the full index of an object in a 2D list (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, object

I have a 2D array of objects like this:

```
a = [
[o1, o2, o3],
[o4, o5, o6],
[o7, o8, o9],
]
```

we have object `obj` which could be any of the objects in the 2D array shown above.

How do I get the full index of obj in the 2D array.
For example, if obj = o6, the solution should return `a[1][2]`

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `loop` with `enumerate`:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

# element that you want to find
b = 2

for i,x in enumerate(a):
    if b in x:
        index_2d = (i, x.index(b))
```

Output:

> ```
> >>> print(index_2d)
> (0, 1)
> >>> print(a[index_2d[0]][index_2d[1]])
> 2
> ```